# Summarise proportion of grouped variable in r

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to summarize a grouped variable, but I want to get the sum as the proportion of the number in each group. Here is an example:

Create the following dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(year = c(rep(1970, 4), rep(1980, 4), rep(1990, 4)), 
                  country = rep(1:4, 3), 
                  change = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, -0.1, NA, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, NA, NA, 0.1, 0.1))
> dat
   year country change
1  1970       1    0.1
2  1970       2    0.1
3  1970       3    0.1
4  1970       4   -0.1
5  1980       1     NA
6  1980       2    0.1
7  1980       3    0.1
8  1980       4    0.1
9  1990       1     NA
10 1990       2     NA
11 1990       3    0.1
12 1990       4    0.1
```

I can generate a count of the number of countries experiencing a positive change:

```
dat %>%
  mutate(change.true = ifelse(change > 0, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(count.positive = sum(change.true))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
   year count.positive
  <dbl>          <dbl>
1  1970              3
2  1980              3
3  1990              2
```

This suggests that the number of countries seeing a positive change is stable or decreasing. However this is an effect of there being a decreasing number of countries for which there is data (I undertstand that i need to treat missing data with caution). What I would like to explore is how the proportion of countries for which there is data is changing. Essentially i want this:

```
data.frame(year = c(1970, 1980, 1990), 
           prop.positive = c(0.75, 1, 1))
  year prop.positive
1 1970          0.75
2 1980          1.00
3 1990          1.00
```

How do I do I amend the summarize function so that I get a count of the group size for each group? I'd be happy to mutate another column with the group size and then calculate the proportion, but don't know how to get that group size. It goes without saying that I am trying to do this for a massive data set.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dplyr to create aggregate percentages of factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857810/dplyr-to-create-aggregate-percentages-of-factor-levels)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the proportion by making use of `na.rm` from the `mean` i.e. get the `mean` of logical expression (`change > 0`) while removing the `NA

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(prop.positive = mean(change > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#   year prop.positive
#  <dbl>         <dbl>
#1  1970          0.75
#2  1980          1   
#3  1990          1
```

If some of the 'country' are missing, then we can do a `complete` on the dataset to get the missing values and then do the `group_by` `summarise`

```
library(tidyr)
dat %>%
  complete(year, country) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(prop.positive = mean(change > 0, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

In `base R`, we can do the same with `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(prop.positive = change > 0) ~ year, dat,
           mean, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = na.pass)
#   year prop.positive
#1 1970          0.75
#2 1980          1.00
#3 1990          1.00
```

Comment: thanks that makes sense. What however, if the person building the database wasn't diligent enough to ensure that all missing data was indicated by NA, and instead some groups simply had less data in them - i.e. 1980 only has countries 2, 3, 4; and 1990 only has countries 3,4?

Comment: @MorrisseyJ  Then you can do a `complete` i.e. `dat %>% group_by(year) %>% complete(country = unique(dat$country))` and do the res

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
dat <- within(dat, prop.positive<-ave(change, year, FUN = function(x) mean(x>0,na.rm = T)))
datout <- unique(dat[c("year","prop.positive")])
```

such that

```
> datout
  year prop.positive
1 1970          0.75
5 1980          1.00
9 1990          1.00
```