# Making a data frame of proportions, by at least 3 separate factors, in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a data frame where I want to calculate a count and a proportion or percentage column by 3 different factors. In this example it would be by state, gender and age.

```
state <- rep(c(rep("Idaho", 10), rep("Maine", 10)), 2)
student.id <- sample(1:1000,8,replace=T)
gender <- rep( c("Male","Female"), 100*c(0.25,0.75) )  
gender <- sample(gender, 40)
age <- rep( c("Primary school","Secondary school"), 100*c(0.5,0.5) )
age <- sample(age, 40)
school.data <- data.frame(student.id, state, gender, age)
```

For calculating this with only 2 factors a very good solution is here:
[dplyr to create aggregate percentages of factor levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857810/dplyr-to-create-aggregate-percentages-of-factor-levels)

But when using the code for >2 factors the solution gives incorrect values in the proportion column. Does anyone know how to find proportions when looking across at least 3 factors?

The code I tried was:

```
proportions <- group_by(school.data, state, gender, age) %>% 
  summarize(n = length(student.id)) %>%
  ungroup %>% group_by(state) %>% 
  mutate(proportion = n / sum(n))
```

In the proportions df I want the proportions to be for example: Idaho female primary school vs Idaho female secondary school. So the proportion based on 1 factor when the other 2 factors are constant. And I would like to calculate those numbers across the whole df. But the proportion numbers the code generates do not match these.

I want the data to be in this format so I can create a stacked bar plot in ggplot with the option to have the count numbers or percentages printed on top of the bars like they are here [Showing data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644997/showing-data-values-on-stacked-bar-chart-in-ggplot2)

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you created a *small* example (say, 10-20 rows) so that the right answer is apparent and it is easy to compare to---with an example that small you could post the right answer in the question. Also, it's nice if you use `set.seed()` before random simulation so everyone can simulate the same data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing "age" in the second gropu_by. the following code seems to produce the right proportions.

```
library(tidyverse)
state <- rep(c(rep("Idaho", 10), rep("Maine", 10)), 2)
student.id <- sample(1:1000,8,replace=T)
gender <- rep( c("Male","Female"), 100*c(0.25,0.75) )  
gender <- sample(gender, 40)
age <- rep( c("Primary school","Secondary school"), 100*c(0.5,0.5) )
age <- sample(age, 40)
school.data <- data.frame(student.id, state, gender, age)

proportions <- group_by(school.data, state, gender, age)%>% 
  summarize(n = length(student.id)) %>%
  ungroup %>% group_by(state, gender) %>% 
  mutate(proportion = n / sum(n))
```

gives

```
State   gender  Age             n   proportion
-------------------------------------------------
Idaho   Female  Primary school  4   0.3076923
Idaho   Female  Secondary school    9   0.6923077
Idaho   Male    Primary school  2   0.2857143
Idaho   Male    Secondary school    5   0.7142857
Maine   Female  Primary school  8   0.5714286
Maine   Female  Secondary school    6   0.4285714
Maine   Male    Primary school  4   0.6666667
Maine   Male    Secondary school    2   0.3333333
```